# Como passar para Array informação de JSON em Swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Quando o resultado vem do servidor uso o seguinte trecho de código para receber o resultado:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value {
      print("JSON: \(JSON)")
}
```

E o resultado do print é:

```
[{
  Nome = Tiago;
  Idade = 22;
  Cidade = Minas;
}, {
  Nome = Luisa;
  Idade = 12;
  Cidade = Califórnia;
}]
```

Como posso fazer para pegar este resultado e colocar em um array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um array de String e receber o resultado do json com ela e depois utilizar em outro método.

Declare no escopo global, isto é no inicio da classe: `var texto: [String] = []`

Depois quando for percorrer o Json para pegar o valor de cada item de um append nele:

```js
Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON {
  response in
if
  let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
let json = JSON(value) print(json) for (_, subJson) in json {
  self.texto.addObject(subJson.object)
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Onde vai buscar esse JSON? visto que não o tem declarado?

Comment: @HideCode Como você colocou a tag Alamofire coloquei um exemplo da requisição, se você quiser testa-lá apenas adicione um `let url = 'caminhoDaRequisicao'` o  conteúdo que resolve a sua dúvida é a declaração do array e a forma como e inserido o resultado do json no  array dentro do for

Comment: Tentei fazer um for para aceder á informação que está dentro do texto mas não me mostra nada. Fiz da seguinte maneira  `for pessoas in self.texto{
                           print(pessoas)
                    }`

Comment: o problema aqui penso que é que eu estou a receber um array com arrays lá dentro. Tentei fazer isto `    let json = JSON(value)
                    for (_, subJson) in json {
                        self.texto.append(subJson.stringValue) // Inserindo valores no array
                        print(self.texto)
                    }` e o resultado que obtive foi "", "" "", "" "" "", "" "" "" ""

Comment: você esta usando ? https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Estou sim, mas por exemplo se eu quiser fazer isto ` let listresultados: Array<JSON> = json["list"].arrayValue
                    
                    for number in listresultados {
                        print(number)
                    }` eu não consigo porque no resultado que vem do servidor na realidade onde está "list" eu tenho "", daí não estar a conseguir ir buscar os dados que vêem

Comment: Consegui a solução e foi a seguinte `        Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
            .responseJSON{
                response in
                if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {

                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json)
                    for (_, subJson) in json {
                        self.texto.addObject(subJson.object)
                    }
                }
        }
`

Comment: @HideCode voce so trocou por addObject ? o append deveria funcionar. editei  resposta para auxiliar alguem que possa ter a mesma duvida.